# Download iOS app and get notified once the download is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there a way to allow a user to download & install an iOS app while using another app and get the notification once the app is downloaded and available to use?

**Problem :**

I have an app (say App1) and i want to check if another app (say App2) is available in the device. If the App2 is not available i need to download from itunes. Once download finished i need to alert user that App2 download has been finished and available to use.

I tried to search for an iTunes API to do this but I did not find anything.

Comment: I don't think this can be accomplished due to Sandboxing, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution would be to attempt to open a URL Scheme specified in App2 from App1. And to poll for it continually from App1 until it is found.

**Objc**

```
- (void)checkForSiblingApp {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<app2scheme>://"]]) {

        //App exists! Show user a message and then call this to open the app
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<app2scheme>://"]];
    } else {

        //App does not exist, check again in 1 minute
        [self performSelector:@selector(checkForSiblingApp) withObject:nil afterDelay:60];
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
func checkForSiblingApp() {

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "<app2scheme>://")!) {

        //App exists! Show user a message and then call this to open the app
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "<app2scheme>://")!)
    } else {

        //App does not exist, check again in 1 minute
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(60 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.checkForSiblingApp()
        }
    }
}
```

This will tell you if your app is available on the device. This is Inter-App Communication and you can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html).

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention in the question, i have tried this approach. Just wanted to check if there is any other way than the approach of applying delay and checking for the availability of app X minute. I just want to alert the user, that download of app from app store is complete. But if i din't find any other solution will accept this as answer.